# DDWRT Repeater Bridge loses Wifi intermittently

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, dd-wrt

Here are my network details:
1. DSL Modem
IP: 192.168.2.1
Model: ZXDSL-831CII 
Firmware: Stock

2. Primary WiFi Router
   IP: 192.168.1.1
   Model: TP Link TL-WDR4300
   Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (03/25/13) std - build 21061
   Configured in AP mode.
   Default settings.
   SSID: Shahjehan2.4GHz
   Security: WPA2 Personal -AES

Guest Network: Virtual Adapter
SSID: ShahjehanGuest
Security: WPA2-Personal TKIP+AES
5GHz Network
SSID: Shahjehan5GHz
Security: WPA2-Personal TKIP+AES

This router is placed next to the DSL Modem and serves the downstairs portion of the house.

3. Repeater Bridge
   IP: 192.168.1.2
   Model: Linksys - WRT54G2
   Firmware:  DD-WRT v24-sp2 (08/07/10) micro - build 14896
   Configured in Repeater Bridge Mode.
   Default Settings.
   SSID Phy: Shahjehan2.4GHz
   SSID Vir: Shahjehan2.4GHz
   Security: WPA2 Personal-AES

This router extends the WiFi network, using the same SSID, upstairs.

Problem: Since I have one SSID, I can't tell which of the routers is the issue but intermittently, WiFi drops and usually reconnects after a few seconds. When this happens, and since I have a dual band router, I can still connect to the 5GHz network on my primary router.

I don't think it's a WiFi Security algorithm issue because it was also working on WPA2- Personal AES + TKIP but I faced the same problem I mentioned above.

I have followed all the instructions on DDWRT Repeater Bridge configuration page but it could be that I have made a mistake somewhere or have not understood something.

The other alternate I can try is to use a different SSID for the virtual adapter in my repeater bridge. This way, the entire WiFi network will not come down but I prefer having it configured it this way, since I don't have to switch connections when moving upstairs and downstairs in the house. I can try that as a last resort but would like to see if something else fixes it first.

Let's talk about SNR, signal quality and noise.
Signal: -66
Noise: -92
SNR: 27
Signal Quality: 35%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this. http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=943088

This is a known issue and there is a chance you'll never find a resolution to this. I've had the same problem and tried multiple things to resolve this and its never fixed it permanently.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234, indeed... the link is dead!